Vertex Positions After Animation for gLTF
I have a mesh that is being rotated and translated and I would like to know the final positions of all vertices after the animation
I'm aware that vertex coordinates are stored in the POSITION attribute of a mesh primitive, but these coordinates only provide the vertex positions prior to animation. If a mesh is animated, are the new vertex positions stored somewhere in the buffer? To my knowledge, the mesh accessors responsible for recording animated coordinates only do so for the mesh origin and not the vertices themselves.

What environment are you in?  Is this C++ on Vulkan or OpenGL? Or Python in Blender? Or Javascript with WebGL?  For the Vulkan/*GL environments, generally the final vertex positions are calculated in the vertex shader itself, and not available to the CPU without replicating the math on the CPU or reading the results back from a GPU compute pass of some kind.

I've been working in MATLAB using this  package to tap the accessor data. So far, I've been calculating final positions by hand but it's becoming increasingly cumbersome (especially for parented meshes). If the calculations were already done somewhere and I could just access it, that would be ideal otherwise it seems I will have to switch environments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
